# Sqlite Cursor not getting data from database

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

I am trying a simple insert and read operation but I am getting exception while doing it so.

Here is the code i am trying,

```
try{
    SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("iTimeDB", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Activities (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ,IMEI VARCHAR, Title VARCHAR, Time VARCHAR);");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Activities(IMEI, Title, Time) VALUES('"+ IMEI +"','"+ title +"','" +time+"');");
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT MAX(ID) FROM Activities", null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    String ID = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("ID"));
    Log.v("column: ID", ID);
    db.close();

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.v("YYY", e.toString());
    }
```

There is no exception while inserting data but when I try to read from DB here is the Exception

Here is the LogCat

```
01-02 11:02:46.992: V/YYY(20510): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row
0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before
accessing data from it.
```

Comment: have you checked the database after inserting the record?

Comment: this is what i have done to check the database . . . well if you remove the Cursor part from code there is no exception

Comment: Checkout the answer because you were passing wrong ColumnIndex

Comment: What values you are passing in `IMEI`,`title` & `time` variables ?

Comment: @Vigbyor: All are Strings. ans from Biraj Zalavadia worked the problem was in Select Statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this way

```
String ID = c.getInt(0);
```

OR

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT MAX(ID)'ID' FROM Activities", null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    String ID = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("ID"));
```

Answer (score 0):

this may be because of your query and the cursor filter

your Query

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT MAX(ID) FROM Activities", null);
```

Try

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT MAX(ID) as newID FROM Activities", null);
```

and instead of `String ID = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("ID"));` use `String ID = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("maxID"));`

Answer (score 0):

you should always check, for cursor wether its able to fetch rows or not using api moveToFirst().

```
if(c.moveToFirst())
{
 String ID = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("ID"));
 Log.v("column: ID", ID);
}
 db.close();
```